# my bot gives everyone role when it should only give the user that trigger it a role

Tags: python, api, discord, discord.py

**I want to make a verify system and this is triggered when I dm the bot but it gives everyone in everyserver the role I just want the user that triggered it to get the role I think the `for user in guild.members:` is the thing that's doing it**

```
user = message.author
guild = client.guilds[0]
Verified = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Verified")

for user in guild.members:
  await user.add_roles(Verified)
message.reply(f'You are verified in {guild}')
```

Comment: Well, you _are_ looping over every guild member, what do you imagine will happen?

Answer (score 4):

What the for loop does is that it goes through every user in the guild. That's why it grants the role to all of them.

Instead, since you already have the author (from `user = message.author`), you can remove the for loop and simply grant them the role:

```py
await user.add_roles(Verified)
```